# Installing libpython-dev

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to install `libpython-dev` on a Travis-CI worker without success. I am using the container-based workers. The relevant section of the `.travis.yml` file follows:

```
sudo: false
language: cpp
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
       # Compilers
      - g++
      - gfortran
      - cmake
       # Libraries for static linking
      - binutils-gold
      - libc6-dev
      - libpthread-stubs0-dev
       # Math libraries
      - libblas-dev
      - liblapack-dev
      - libatlas-base-dev
       # MPI
      - openmpi-bin
      - libopenmpi-dev
       # Python library, development version
      - libpython-dev
```

I get the following error: `E: Unable to locate package libpython-dev`
even though the package is on the [ubuntu-precise whitelist](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/blob/master/ubuntu-precise)

Comment: any updates on this one? Today I ran in a very similar situation with the gcovr package https://travis-ci.org/finklabs/epiclibs/builds/83061222